# Problem with the import bluetooth!

Tags: python, bluetooth, bluez

I have tried a lot of this lines programs but the terminal it keep's complaint.

Error message:
`Import Error:No module named bluetooth._bluetooth`

I have install some lib but again the problem it shows. The code is not mine, I have take from here: https://github.com/bowdentheo/BLE-Beacon-Scanner/blob/master/BeaconScanner.py

--Part code:

```
import ScanUtility
import bluetooth._bluetooth as bluez

#Set bluetooth device. Default 0.
dev_id = 0
try:
  sock = bluez.hci_open_dev(dev_id)
  print ("\n *** Looking for BLE Beacons ***\n")
  print ("\n *** CTRL-C to Cancel ***\n")
except:
  print ("Error accessing bluetooth")

ScanUtility.hci_enable_le_scan(sock)
#Scans for iBeacons
try:
  while True:
      returnedList = ScanUtility.parse_events(sock, 10)
      for item in returnedList:
          print(item)
          print("")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  pass
```

Comment: `import bluetooth._bluetooth as bluez` ... are you sure that there should be a period in the name?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.